# Bootstrap 3 glyph icons don't show up in jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can anyone tell my why glyphs don't show up in this jsfiddle?
http://jsfiddle.net/csabatoth/yB84b/2/

HTML:

```
<a id="blabla" href="#"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

As you see the fiddle is based on Knockout 3.0.0.
Besides that I include jQuery 1.11.1, jQuery-UI 1.10.4, Bootstrap 3.1.1.
What am I doing wrong?
Note: in a complex example later I need to use Bootstrap+Knockout, that's why they are included.

Comment: This is most likely caused by missing font files or wrong font file path.

Comment: Both of the two answers are correct below, but I don't know which came first. Bootstrap 3 not only have different classes for the grid layouting, but for the icons too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your icon classes are wrong.  The classnames can be found at http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Your HTML should read

```
<a id="blabla" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yB84b/4/

Comment: Thanks! I marked your answer first, I didn't see who answered first.

Answer (score 3):

You have the class name from Bootstrap 2, but you're using Bootstrap 3. Change the class to:

```
<a id="blabla" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yB84b/5/